# libpam-winbind package for samba users

Tags: samba

Installing the libpam-winbind package will sync the system users to the samba user database. This is written in the documentation. I'm not sure about the sync. After installing the libpam-winbind package, if I lock the passwd for the system user, then the samba client with the same name cannot connect to the samba server? I could test it by myself, but I did too many test so I'm not sure about the specific instance of this kind.

Comment: Is your samba server part of and authenticating against a domain controller?  If not, libpam-winbind will not work as planned.  See:  https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/pam_winbind.8.html  What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: It is a file server. and I followed your link. Do you understand it? I don't get it at all.

Comment: Yes I do understand it.  Do you have a Windows Active Domain Server controlling the users?  Or are they controlled only on the file server itself?

Comment: Now I'm making it simple, and I want to expand it to get the concept of whole things about Samba 4 and windows ADDS. Honestly I'm not sure I can achieve the satisfying level. I don't want to stop at the level of inputting a little command on the terminal. You said you understand the pam module. You also seem to understand the ADDS in windows domain. Is there any path to get the goal?

Comment: I would recommend https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee797058(v=cs.20).aspx and https://www.tecmint.com/join-ubuntu-to-active-directory-domain-member-samba-winbind/ to help you get to your goal.  We unfortunately cannot help you decide the path that you want to take to obtain your goal.  That is for you to decide on how you want to configure your server and your user accounts.

Comment: It seems that I need a seperate computer for testing ADDS. It's gonna take some time.